# UIImagePickerController preview image shifts down

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I know there are questions from several years ago on this topic, but I think their solutions are out of date and/or I can't get them to work. I tried all the info.plist changes, etc.

I'm using UIImagePickerController. After taking a photo, the preview image (with Retake and Use photo options) jumps down about 20 pixels. It seems like it's occupying the mediaTypes toolbar area.

Any suggestions for how to prevent the image from shifting? Here's the relevant code (very basic)

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [picker prefersStatusBarHidden];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

After trying a lot of config stuff that didn't work, I took a simple approach and forced the camera view down by the same number of pixels that the preview image was shifting using a transform, i.e.

```
picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(picker.cameraViewTransform, 0.0, 30.0);
```

The whole method:

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;

    picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(picker.cameraViewTransform, 0.0, 30.0);

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```